# Maintainable design pattern advice

Tags: design-patterns

I'm working on a project that has different price calculations for different services.
For example:

- Home Services: based on number of kitchens, bedrooms, bathrooms
- Baby Sitting: based on time of day and week, number of hours (including overtime)
- Car Washing: based on size of the car, number of seats

Each service calculates the cost differently based on those aspects. The number of services will increase, so a specific function for each service might eventually be too much to maintain.

What kind of design pattern can I use to make sure my code will still be maintainable in the long run?

Comment: Home Services, Baby Sitting, Car Washing, Are you writing an X-rated movie??? sorry couldn't hold it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) can help here.

Your component will be of type `Service` and you may subclass it into `HomeServices`, `BabySitting`, `CarWashing`. So one actor can perform 2 or three or many tasks and get payed once, each subclass has its own payment calculation with `int addCost(int cost)` and recursively `addCost()` of its service member to calculate the final cost, you can even add different tasks by adding a new subclass per task.

Comment: IMO, DEcorator doesn't help here, the OP don't want to add new behaviour to existing classes. Also I wouldn't use inheritance for this purpose as BabySitting calculations are quite different than CarWashing. It's much better to have each kind of service unrelated to each other while their "common" behaviour will amount to some utilities methods in a static class, methods neutral to all services.

Comment: Everything is based on requirement, as I understood it, the services might be provided by a company that just do so, and there are many services, and the billing is different for each service, but it's billing! so I would use decorator and make billing method abstract.

Comment: "The number of services will increase"

Comment: Yes, it's billing but HOW the price will be calculated will vary. One method is not enough since each service may require specific dependencies that are not common. IMO your solution is too complicated to maintain on the long run.

Comment: "HOW the price will be calculated will vary,One method is not enough since each service may require specific dependencies that are not common" just you have one abstract billing method and every class may define its helper methods.

Answer (score 0):

Strategy pattern comes to mind, but you'll still be writing a "function", more exactly a class, for each strategy. With a DI COntainer you won't have a problem, regardless of the number of strategies.

There aren't magic design patterns that diminish the amount of code needed for your app, the only thing you can do is to organise the code better.

Answer (score 0):

Warlock is right, decorator is a way to go with dynamic pricing. Many services (services in here is assumed as BLL classes) will be needed, but not too much since it will match your business need.

What you need is 2 interface, one generic service interface and one pricing base interface. In C#:

```
interface IBillParameter{
    decimal DefaultCost { get; } // this is assumed if you has default fixed cost, but may be ignored
}

interface IBillCalculator<T> where T : IBillParameter{
    decimal Calculate(T parameter);
}
```

The implementation, such as `CarServices`:

```
class CarServiceBillParameter :IBillParameter {
    decimal DefaultCost { get{ return 0; } } // for example if does not has any fixed cost
    SizeF CarSize { get;set; }
    int Seat { get;set; }
}

class CarFixedCostBillCalculator : IBillCalculator<CarServiceBillParameter>{
    decimal Calculate(CarServiceBillParameter parameter){
        return parameter.DefaultCost; // this can be replaced by database call, or zero for null pattern
    }
}

class SeatCarServiceBillCalculator : IBillCalculator<CarServiceBillParameter>{
    public SeatCarServiceBillCalculator(IBillCalculator<CarServiceBillParameter> baseCalculator){
        this.baseCalculator = baseCalculator;
    }
    IBillCalculator<CarServiceBillParameter> baseCalculator;
    decimal Calculate(CarServiceBillParameter parameter){
        decimal eachSeatPrice = GetFromDatabase();
        return parameter.Seat * eachSeatPrice + baseCalculator.Calculate(parameter);
    }
}
```

This way, if you need to add more logic, you only need to introduce new classes, for example different price by number of tires.

Comment: thanks for the example.  In my case at the moment they just added House Keeping which its pricing based on based price times how many hours the client want to book, other service is Home Cleaning which the price is based on the calculation of how many bedroom,kitcchen, bathroom and other rooms with potentionally other optional booking like window cleaning against the pricing index. The problem is my client company tend to change their pricing model too quick and i am exhousted to accomodate their needs.